# Why doesn't one approach to setting prop work (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Commment.isDefault evaluates to 'true' or 'false'.

The goal is to dynamically update a checkbox.

This works:

```
if (Comment.isDefault == 'false'){
  // console.log("Checked.");
  $('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', true);
}
else {
  // console.log("NOT Checked.");
  $('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', false);
}
```

This does not work:

```
$('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', Comment.isDefault);
```

The non-working case just makes every checkbox TRUE.

I'd like the more elegant solution plus understanding why just using the variable to set the property doesn't work.

Thoughts? Much appreciated!

Comment: if Comment.isDefault is a string, it will result in setting it to true even if that string is "false". your check leads me to think it is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try this:

```
 console.log(typeof Comment.isDefault); // string
 console.log(typeof "false"); // string
 console.log(typeof false); // bool
```

Also not empty string are alway `true` ( the `!` return the inverse boolean, so `!!` return the boolean equivalent)

```
 console.log(!!"true") // true 
 console.log(!!"false") // true 
 console.log(!!"") // false 
 console.log(!!true) // true
 console.log(!!false) // false
```

You have to update (best choice):

```
 Comment.isDefault = true; // or = false; instead of 'true'
```

Or you can also test the string value (if you can't easily update the `Comment.isDefault` value):

```
$('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', Comment.isDefault == 'true');
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `false != 'false'`.

`Comment.isDefault` contains a string, not a boolean. Non-empty strings are *always* truthy. I'd suggest converting your boolean string into a proper boolean value then use it as such.

```
Comment.isDefault = (Comment.isDefault === 'true');
```

Answer (score 1):

> Because your `Comment.isDefault` is having string value of `'true'` or
>   `'false'`

Setting `non-empty` string value in place of `boolean`, evaluates as true. Thus, all `checkboxes` are set to `true`.

**Possible elegant looking solution**

`$('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', JSON.parse(Comment.isDefault));`

**Possible faster solution** (I will pick this over elegant one, thanks to [@arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929632/arthur))

`$('#chkDefault'+ i).prop('checked', Comment.isDefault == "true");`

[JsFilddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/cbL3azjy/)

Comment: For false it is not working, but for true it is working with string

Comment: because all non-empty strings are evaluated as truthy. This is expected, and explained.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai before making unusual assertions - check your assuption. https://jsfiddle.net/b7hjhve2/

Comment: @rlemon, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: I think `Comment.isDefault == "true"` is way faster than `JSON.parse`